# How to improve execution time when calculating prime factors

Tags: c, math, factorial, prime-factoring

I have to make a program to find the largest way to show a n! number (excluding the 1).

**for example: 4! = 1x2x3x4 = 1x2x3x2x2. so you can use the product of 5 numbers to show the 4!.
so the imput is 4 and the output is 5.
5 is the max amount of numbers with which you can express the 4!.**

In simple words is factorize a factorial number in prime factors, count how many they are and show it.

What I did was a 'for' cycle where I count all the prime factors of 1 to 'n' and amount of them.

But I have a problem with big numbers like when 'n' is 100000, it takes 8 seconds to complete. I need to improve the speed.

I think the problem is in the factorization function.

```
int factors( int fact )
{
    int i,cont,product=1, control;
    cont=0;
    control=fact;
    for (i= 2;control != product;)
    {
        if ((fact%i == 0))
        {
            cont++;
            fact/=i;
            product*=i;}
        else
        i++;
    }
    return cont;
}
```

I need to improve it to get a best execution time. Or maybe the method that i'm using to get the prime factors from a factorial number isn't a good option?

**NOTE: I do not calculate the value of 100000!. I just factorize all the numbers from 1 to 10000 and count them.**

Comment: `4!` does not equal `1x2x3x4x5`

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to calculate the value of `100000!`? Do you have any idea [just how big that number is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100000!)?

Comment: C numbers (even `long long`) have a limited size (often 64 bits). And just `1000!` is a very big number (and `100000!` is *huge*). You need [bignums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) to represent it exactly. But that is not for beginners in C (when you are more fluent in C, consider using http://gmplib.org/ ...)

Comment: BTW, you could consider that as an arithmetic (or number theory) math exercise. Hint: you might not need to compute `100!` to get its largest prime factor.

Comment: if 7! is the input. the output is 8 (2x3x2x2x5x2x3x7)... i'am not calculating the valor of 7!, just the number of prime factors.

Comment: @FiddlingBits tell that to my teacher lol. I think this is not a hard problem to solve if u don't care about how much time it's gonna take. the execution time isn't a requirement of the homework i'm just obsessed to improve that time.

Comment: I'm not sure that the factors function is your problem - I ran it on all numbers from 1 to 100,000 and it only took about 3 seconds for all of them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int *prime;
int prime_n;

void make_prime_table(int n){
    prime = malloc(sizeof(int) * n / 2);
    prime_n =0;
    prime[prime_n++] = 2;
    prime[prime_n++] = 3;
    int i, j;
    for(i = 5; i <= n; i +=2){
        bool is_prime = true;
        for(j = 1; j < prime_n ; ++j){
            int t = prime[j];
            if(t * t > i)
                break;
            if(i % t == 0){
                is_prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(is_prime)
            prime[prime_n++] = i;
    }
}

int factors(int fact_n ){
    int i, c, p, sum=0;
    for(i = 0; i < prime_n ; ++i){
        c = fact_n;//number of prime in N : (x1 = N / P) + (x2 = x1 / P) + ...
        while(c = c / prime[i]){
            sum += c;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(void){
    int n = 100000;
    make_prime_table(n);
    int ans = factors(n);
    printf("ans = %d\n", ans);

    free(prime);
    return 0;
}
```

---

number of prime P in N! :
case of 2 in 10!

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  *   *   *   *    * # There are 5 number that is divided by 2. 5 = 10 / 2  
      *       *      # Number that can be divided further part of the mark of `*`(5/2).  
              *      # The number of total is the number of `*`.
```

*search "theorem of Legendre"

Comment: well... that it's the entire answer... i'm very thankful with you but i feel if i read or copy your answer i'am gonna learn anything... if you give my tips how to go to get a better time i'm gonna be very thankful.

Comment: Ok, i don't get that theorem yet (lol), but i took from you code the idea of make a prime table to use in the code (and not call a function to see if a number is prime every time), and from 8 seconds i improve the time to 1 s,  so thanks you! it's maybe not to much but i prefer to go by my way and not copy any code... Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, i got the theorem, now only take a fraction of second. Thank you very much!